# Filter Duplicate Elements in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, time-limit-exceeded

I'm working on HackerRank to try to improve my Haskell skills along side with reading Haskell Programming from first principles. I wrote a program that works, but it seems to time out on large input sets. The purpose of the program is

> Given a list of `n` integers `a = [a1, a2, ..., an]`, you have to find those integers which are repeated at least `k` times. In case no such element exists you have to print `-1`.
>
> If there are multiple elements in `a` which are repeated at least `k` times, then print these elements ordered by their first occurrence in the list.

So I wrote a few different functions to help with this.

#### `count` which counts the number of occurrences of an element in a list

```hs
count :: Eq a => Integral b => a -> [a] -> b
count e [] = 0
count e (a:xs) = (count e xs +) $ if a == e then 1 else 0
```

#### `uniq` which removes duplicates from a list

```hs
uniq :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
uniq x [] = x 
uniq [] (a:xs) = uniq [a] xs
uniq x (a:xs) = if a `elem` x then uniq x xs else uniq (a:x) xs
```

#### `filt` which filters through a list and removes elements that don't occur at least `k` times.

```hs
filt :: Show a => Num a => Read a => Eq a => Integral b => [a] -> b -> [a]
filt a b = reverse $ uniq [] [i | i <- a, count i a >= b]
```

#### `printList` which prints a list as a space separated list or prints `-1` if the list is empty.

```hs
printList :: Show a => [a] -> IO ()
printList [] = putStrLn "-1"
printList a = putStrLn $ unwords [show i | i <- a]
```

#### `readNumbers` which takes a space separated string and returns a `Num` list from that string.

```hs
readNumbers :: Show a => Eq a => Num a => Read a => String -> [a]
readNumbers = map read . words
```

#### `run` which throws all of this together and runs this `n` times.

```hs
run :: (Show a, Eq a, Num a, Read a) => a -> IO ()
run 0 = putStr ""
run n = do
  a <- getLine
  b <- getLine
  printList $ filt (readNumbers b) (readNumbers a !! 1)
  run $ n - 1
```

#### `main` the main function. It gets a number `n` and then calls `run n`.

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = do
  a <- getLine
  run $ read a
```

This code works, for example, with the input

```hs
3
9 2
4 5 2 5 4 3 1 3 4
9 4
4 5 2 5 4 3 1 3 4
10 2
5 4 3 2 1 1 2 3 4 5
```

and gives the desired output of

```hs
4 5 3
-1
5 4 3 2 1
```

However, with larger datasets this code is incredibly slow. I'm guessing it's because the recursion is less than optimal, but I can't really pinpoint what is taking so long. My best guess is that `uniq` or `count` is the limiting factor, but I can't figure out how to optimize them.

Comment: The primary problem is `uniq`, `count`, and `filt` are all O(n). Take a look at https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers and see if there is a data structure that would work better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you write uniq as a right fold, you don't need to pass an accumulator through, and the list comes out in the right order:

```
uniq :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
uniq [] = []
uniq (x:xs) = (if x `elem` xs then id else (x:)) $ uniq xs

filt :: Show a => Num a => Read a => Eq a => Integral b => [a] -> b -> [a]
filt k is = uniq [i | i <- is, count i is >= k]
```

(Edit: Actually that one throws out the first of each two equal elements, not the last. Here`s one without that problem:

```
uniq :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
uniq [] = []
uniq (x:xs) = x : uniq (filter (/=x) xs)
```

)

You've commendably already brought `count` into a form that allows it to be written in terms of library combinators:

```
count :: Eq a => Integral b => a -> [a] -> b
count e = sum . map (\a -> if a == e then 1 else 0)
```

That's a bit ugly due to lambdas though, here's a nicer version:

```
count e = length . filter (== e)
```

For separation of monadic and pure code (and generally for factoring out common code from across cases), here's a `showList` to replace `printList`:

```
showList :: Show a => [a] -> String
showList [] = "-1"
showList a = unwords [show i | i <- a]
```

Calling a monadic action a given number of times doesn't need manual recursion, and thus also doesn't need to give the repeated action a name:

```
main :: IO () 
main = do
  a <- readLn
  replicateM_ a $ do
    [_n, k] <- map read . words <$> getLine
    numbers <- map read . words <$> getLine
    putStrLn $ showList $ filt k numbers
```

(I think `readNumbers` doesn't deserve a name.)

In case the order in which the output is given isn't important, here's a version that doesn't require quadratic time because each element is compared to every other:

```
filt k = map head . filter ((>=k) . length) . group . sort
```

which relies on `Data.List`s `sort` being faster than quadratic time.

Comment: You are some type of Haskell wizard here. This is an absolutely beautiful piece of code.